# NodeJS Render parameter to local JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for an information.
How to pass a variable from NodeJS `res.render('index', { title: "Hey"})` to local JS.

I use express (with helmet) and PugJs. I can include my var in the template, but I want to store it on the JS file who's part of the template. (No inline script, vanilla JS)

Currently, I use a hidden Input in the template to store the data, the JS script get the input and do the work.
How I can pass the variable thought the template to my JS file?

Sorry, I 'm French :(
Thank you for your time!

Comment: why don't want put inline script in the template file as part of template and this script can put the variable in to global object (window) where will be disposed to your script. ?

Comment: Helmet block inline script (Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'") ; Is it safe to enable the "unsafe-inline" ?

Comment: ok. now i gotch you point .so basically you have to dynamic create js script file witch will be attached to your template. I that case you can cretea some FileWrite and just output fille.

Comment: Oh ok, so before the res.render i create a new js with the variable after that i pass the name of the js script in the render. So in the template i've a dynamic var to include the created script. I'll try that ! Thank you !!

Comment: It works! Thank you again :) is there a negative impact to creating a file for each render?
or can i use only one file ?

Comment: I don't thinks so... services somtimes create many big files in fly. You can use only one file if this varialbe don't chage value. or dont change to often. then you can store file with name value in name of this file. kind of cache.